# Why does my image doesn't show in imageView?

Tags: xml, imageview, android-imageview, android-cardview

so I am working with my project using android studio. I created a simple xml with CardView and used an ImageView in it. Code bellow:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="3dp"
                app:cardMaxElevation="20dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_illustration" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

But when I run the app, the image doesn't appear. It should be look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS72j.png), but it look  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3zsw.png) instead. Is it because the image is too big?(i download the img from google image). How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
.
...
...
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView3"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_illustration"
/>
```